Prove that $T_{n}$ is the $n$th term of a GP.
Let $a, b, c$ be some constants, and $T_{n}, S_{n}$ be the $n$th terms of some (different) sequences such that:
$$
\begin{align}
T_{n} & = \cfrac{2a(b-2S_{n})}{(a+c)^{2}}
\\ S_{1} & = 0
\\ S_{n} & = c \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} T_{i} \;\;\;\;\;\; \text{if $n\in N,$ $n\neq$1}
\end{align}
$$
Prove that the sequence whose $n$th term is represented by $T_{n}$ is a GP.
This is not a question from a maths book, this arose while I was trying to solve a Physics question in a slightly more convoluted way, but I think the context of the Physics problem here is irrelevant.
I'm reasonably certain that this is a GP because I found the first 3 terms from the above, and they were in a GP with common ratio $\cfrac{(a-c)^{2}}{(a+c)^{2}}$. Also, the sum of infinite terms of this GP (which was required in the Physics question) matches the answer found in the "normal" way. But I can't figure it out how to prove that it is a GP.

First, I must say, amazing question!
Second, I must say, amazing question, given it pops somewhere from physics, meaning it shows how close our physical world is to mathematics.
Third, I would appreciate if you provide the physics question on the physics stack exchange as a quiz question maybe... because I am deeply intrigued!!)
Last, my solution is provided below, (SE formatting police, I promise I will type it all out as soon as possible and edit the answer)


*By the way, Oops! The last 'three steps of page 1' and 'first four steps of page 2' were unnecessary...
((Now I can proudly say it can be solved in one page))
Kindly comment for any clarification, hope this helps!

The question I was talking about: https://imgur.com/a/E3WTNsn.

An alternative way to do this which is simpler, don't know why I didn't try this earlier:
$$ 
\begin{align}
\cfrac{T_{n+1}}{T_{n}} & = \cfrac{b-2S_{n+1}}{b-2S_{n}} 
\\ & = \cfrac{b-2c\sum_{i=1}^{n}T_{i}}{b-2c\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}T_{i}}
\\ & = 1- \cfrac{2cT_{n}}{b-2c\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}T_{i}}
\\ & = 1- \cfrac{2cT_{n}}{b-2S_{n}}
\\ & = 1- \cfrac{4ac}{(a+c)^2}  \;\;\;  \text{(From expression of $T_{n}$ given)}
\\ & = \cfrac{(a-c)^{2}}{(a+c)^{2}}
\end{align}
$$
Since ratio of consecutive terms is a constant and independent of $n$, this is a GP.
